# LWC [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')]

Tags: lightning-web-components, superbadges

I am stuck on this error.

> [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')]

Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

I checked my `boatSearchForm.js` and `getBoatTypes` is imported.

Can someone enlighten me on how to solve this problem?

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
const TILE_WRAPPER_SELECTED_CLASS = 'tile-wrapper selected';
const TILE_WRAPPER_UNSELECTED_CLASS = 'tile-wrapper';

export default class BoatTile extends LightningElement {
    @api boat;
    @api selectedBoatId;
    
    // Getter for dynamically setting the background image for the picture
    get backgroundStyle() {
        return `background-image:url(${this.boat.Picture__c})`;
     }
    
    // Getter for dynamically setting the tile class based on whether the
    // current boat is selected
    get tileClass() { 
        // return this.selectedBoatId == this.boatId ? TILE_WRAPPER_SELECTED_CLASS : TILE_WRAPPER_UNSELECTED_CLASS;
        return this.selectedBoatId ? TILE_WRAPPER_SELECTED_CLASS : TILE_WRAPPER_UNSELECTED_CLASS;
    }
    
    // Fires event with the Id of the boat that has been selected.
    selectBoat() { 
        const boatselectEvent = new CustomEvent('boatselect', { 
            detail: { boatId : this.boat.id}
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(boatselectEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls provide at least the boteTile.js

Comment: Hi @Damecek, I added the tiles.js

Comment: the error basically means that some variable is `undefined` but you are trying to access the `Name` attribute of this object.

Comment: in the boatTile.js I don't see you would be accessing the `Name` property, so it is probably somewhere else in your app. Probably if you are getting the boat record from database, please ensure that you really receive some records. for example the `@wire` adapter is firing multiple times before returning any data.

Comment: your boatTile html file. are you iterating over your boats and trying to access the Name property? you should add an if:true directive to verify the property is not undefined if this is the case

Answer (score 2):

I think you must have some markup like this in your `html` file:

```
{boat.BoatType__r.Name}
```

Instead you should validate if `boat.BoatType__r` is not `null` or `undefined`

```
<template if:true={boat}>
    <template if:true={boat.BoatType__r}>
        {boat.BoatType__r.Name}
    </template>
</template>
```